# Caption of Panel is not aligned like captions of other components in Form

Tags: vaadin

we're using a Form instance of vaadin. Now the TreeTable or TextFields have their captions on the left of the component. But at the panel the caption is above the panel and not on the left.

Is there a way to fix it? For example by placing a caption manually or telling the panel, that their caption is like a normal caption?

Fabian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vaadin most of the components delegate their caption handling to the parent component container. However, it's possible that a component handles its caption by itself. Button and Panel are examples of such components.

You can solve your problem by wrapping the Panel inside a CssLayout and by moving the caption from the Panel to the layout.